# Split method creates empty elements in Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have the following String "Make Me A SandWich"
Someone decided to troll me and replace the spaces with a random number of LOL.
so now the string is "LOLMakeLOLLOLLOLMELOLALOLSandWich"

My goal is to revert this change.

I tried to create a string array with split method but this caused "empty" elements inside of the array that has a value but when I try to log it, it doesn't show anything. It's also not equal to ""

```
Public class MyClass{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String trollText = "MakeLOLLOLLOLMELOLALOLSandWich";

        String[] array = trollText.split("LOL");

        if (array[1]=="")System.out.print("it's an empty string");
        if (array[1]==" ")System.out.print("it's a space sign");
        if (array[1]==null)System.out.print("it's equal to nothing");
        if (array[1]==' '+"")System.out.print("I don't know what's that");
        else System.out.print(array[1]+"<-- This is an element and it has a value");
    }
}
```

I consider the problem solved if someone tells me what array[1] equals to.
Knowing the value will give me something to compare to when copying the elements into a new array.

Comment: What if the original string contains LOL ?

Comment: The question is: WHY? Why don't you simply use a `replace()` method?

Comment: @user1474111 we can assume that it doesn't contain LOL.

Comment: @Amongalen this would leave me with duplicate spaces, which still isn't the answer am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing two strings in java, you cannot use `==` operator which compares object references. You need to use `array[1].equals("")`

Also, if you simply want to replace all occurrences of a string, you can do following

`trollText.replaceAll("LOL", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

To compare Strings in Java, use:

```
String.equals("text");
```

This will return `true` if the Strings are identical and `false` if not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. skipping `empty` or `" "` string and appending `notEmpty values` to `new StringBuilder()` and finally print it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class LOL_problem {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String trollText = "MakeLOLLOLLOLMELOLALOLSandWich";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] array = trollText.split("LOL");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

        for (String str : array) {
            if (!str.equals("")) sb.append(str+" ");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString().trim());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We should use equals(String str) method to check if strings are equals instead of '==' which does object reference check.
To replace all the occurrence, you can use trollText.replaceAll method as below.

```
    public class MyClass{
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String trollText = "MakeLOLLOLLOLMELOLALOLSandWich";
        String result  = trollText.replaceAll("LOL", " ");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```